# How do I get my old account back after my phone got stolen?

Tags: clash-of-clans

My phone was stolen couple weeks ago so I got a new one. I downloaded the clash of clash got the same Google account, but the game made me start from the beginning... How do I do get my old account back?

Comment: Have you tried to connect to Google previously? IIRC if you connected your game to a Google account (via settings), you can get it back by connecting to the same Google account again

Answer (score 1):

Just when you start a new game and the villager appears, there is option (see top left of screen of phone/tablet) to sign in to google account.

then choose your google account. wait for a prompt to load your village. press ok; and game restarts with loading your account.

Comment: I am assuming you **did** google+ signin in phone back then..

Answer (score 0):

If you did in fact backup your save with your google account. Go to setting and find the option to restore the save.

Answer (score 0):

Most games save to the account not the phone. Your best bet (now and for future) is to sign into your main gmail when you set up any new Android phone. Your contacts will transfer, you won't have to repurchase any apps that cost money, and more importantly, **for online games. Your saves will transfer over**.